# why do we need to input strings and then parse them into integer when one can input integers?

Tags: java

This might be a very basic question but i really i did not understand the purpose of doing so . guessing rather wildly that can be a efficiency or performance, security strength ( I really do not understand the purpose though)

Comment: What is the difference between a string and an integer to a computer?

Comment: How would you input an integer??

Comment: It all depends on context.  From a console point of view, there is no way in Java to parse each character as the user inputs, instead, we get back a single value.  You may wish to do some validation on the value before passing it to the rest of the program, otherwise you would end up with some kind of parser for format exception...

Comment: Input from the console is always initally a string. That's just how it is.

Comment: i was mainly speaking about the use of parseInt method

Answer (score 1):

Okay, technically speaking, from a technical and literal point of view, you *are* putting in numerical values.  But, these numerical values are defined as characters - letters, numbers, symbols, and even some non-printing symbols as well.

For a computer, it's all numbers. But, they have a special way to represent numerical constructs, such as an integer, or a rational/real number, and so forth.

The primary reason that you can't just directly put numbers in is because the numbers you're putting in mean something else in another way.  You have to convert your number from whatever encoding it is (either ASCII or UTF-8 or some other encoding), and give it value inside of an appropriate numerical construct.

Take for instance, the character '0'.  It has a code point value (in UTF-8 and likely ASCII) of 48.  If we were to take '0' at its literal code point value, we would get wonky* results for our math.

There's also the case that you're not just putting numbers in - you're also putting in other letters, symbols, and (God help you if you don't have UTF-8) s̈́̊̄̂ͯ̍ͤo̓̃̈̈́-c̑̋a̅ll̑̓̒ͪͦ̚e̓ͭ̔̋́̚d ͛̄ͧͯ"ͬͭ̎͆Z̋̓̈̈́a͗̇̑l͑̒ͣ̌̈́̚g̋ͦ͑o͆̉̍ͮiͩ̽̎̌̾͆͛z͂̾̓ͯͭe̋ͪ̀͆̇ͪ͂d̄ͫ"̾ͮ̎̽ ̔̿̽ͬC̑͂ͬ͒J̇̔ͤK̇ͩ̂̇͑ c͒̈̾ȟ͌͒ͪ̂ͪa̽ͣ̃̑r͂̓͛͑̐ác̉ͨ̉͆͆ͦ̄t̃ͮ̋̓̚eͧ̽͋ͬ̀ͮr͋͋͑ͩͦ̐̅sͯͬ͋͛ͬ́!̓ͤ̌ͯ̃ͫ̀!̐̇ͫ́!͒ ͂̏͆̌誠̃ͦ̓͛̉̚

Again, these are all numbers to the computer, but these numbers mean something different to the computer than they do you.

To keep things simple, the **chief interaction** that the user will have with the computer will be to **input strings**, since numbers don't entirely convey words or phrases, unless one exclusively spoke and read binary (which would, again, have to be translated into words that *others* could read).

<sup>*:  For addition and subtraction, your results would be off by 48, but this would make multiplication and division *really* exciting.</sup>

---

So, with the above said, let's take a simple example:  We need to convert the input "012817" to a number of some kind.  Let's assume base 10 (0 through 9).

As a computer, I see this come across as:

```
48, 49, 50, 56, 49, 55
```

Since 48 is going to be our zero, we can safely say that, whenever we encounter a character that we wish to convert to an actual numeral, we subtract 48 from it.  Simple!

```
48 - 48, 49 - 48, 50 - 48, 56 - 48, 49 - 48, 55 - 48
0, 1, 2, 8, 1, 7
```

Since leading zeroes are meaningless in base 10, it is discarded, and we can store this in a numerical construct now:

```
12817
```

So what happens if you enter in a non-numeral?  Well, given that the numbers are contiguous*, we can add ten to 48 and know that 58 is the highest base 10 number we will come across.  That gives us a convenient property - if the difference between our character and 48 is greater than 58, we can't place it into a numerical construct**.  And we should blow up, complain, and whine, and give the user this friendly exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.stackoverflow.sandbox.Formatting.main(Formatting.java:19)
```

If you were using base 16 (0 through 9, and A through F, case insensitive), you could have a little bit more leeway into what you allowed.  If you knew where 'A' and 'a' started (65 and 97, respectively), you could expand your conversion algorithm to respect a value that included either case of the letter A, up to and including a value that included either case of the letter F.

<sup>*: At least in ASCII and UTF-8, they are.  Other encodings with other numeral systems may differ.</sup>

<sup>**: Again, we're speaking about base 10.  Higher bases may allow you to add more characters, but that depends on your conversion algorithm.  I've deliberately kept it simple to illustrate the basics.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading user input, say with a Scanner object. If the input is a number only, you can certainly read it with the nextInt() method of the Scanner class. If, however, the number is imbedded within a string of other nonnumerical characters, it has to be parsed.  Anything from the command line is considered a string of characters and it is passed into the main method via the String[] args parameter. Those must be parsed because they are considered embedded within a string. Also, keep in mind that a string is not a primitive data type. It is a String with a capital "S" because it is an object level data structure in Java. So, number characters embedded within it cannot be processed as a primitive integers.